# Lucene 5.3 term vector

Tags: lucene

I am moving from Lucene 3 to Lucene 5.3 and I am having a problem to convert a line of code.

I used to pass the fields *Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES*

And now, with this code:

```
Document.Add(new TextField("Tags", Data.Tags, Field.Store.YES));
```

I do not know how to pass the TermVector field so that the tag words can be looked up.
The 5.3 doc is essentially a class list with no real explanation about anything and while Lucene 3 has a lot of info in forums, I can't find anything about 5.3 yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a change that occurred in Lucene 4.0, so you may be looking over the wrong resources to understand this one.  It's covered in the [4.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html) (look for the section titled "Separate IndexableFieldType from Field instances")

You need to define a `FieldType` to pass into a the `Field` constructor.  If you mostly want `TextField` behavior, but with term vectors, you can copy the standard FieldTypes of TextField, and modify them, something like this:

```java
FieldType myFieldType = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_NOT_STORED);
myFieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
...
Field f = new Field("Tags", Data.Tags, myFieldType);
```

Comment: I had skipped Lucene 4.0, so I totally missed the change! Now I understand how it fits with the new API. Thanks!